# Don't understand the balance of forces

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

A luggage with two wheels, ( but I don't care about them, it is just to say that touches the ground in two points) is being pulled by a force $F$ at an angle $\theta$ from the horizontal.

Now I understand that when if it moves at constant velocity, then I can use the conditions for equilibrium and put:
\begin{equation}
\sum_i{F_i} = 0 \,\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\,\sum_i{r_i\times F_i}
\end{equation}
So the sum of all the forces and the torques is equal to zero. (Considering friction, resistance force and weight). Are the above equations correct?

Comment: Before it was edited to take out most of the description of the luggage, this was a reasonable question with a reasonable answer. The answer to the edited question is, of course the equations are correct, but you have to translate the word problem to the format of these equations correctly. If you have a doubt about how these equations apply to your question, it may be better to revert this question to its original form and ask a new question instead, explaining exactly why you doubt the application of the equations.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The torque "describes " a  rotation due to a force; it plays the same role of a force but in rotating case, in fact many equation for forces and torques are similar. So in this exercise, if we take the rear wheel as pole for calculating torque, $W$ would rotate the luggage downward (or we can say clockwise if we imagine an axis through the rear wheel perpendicular to the sheet) whereas $T$ upward (or counterclockwise). Hence if the torque of $T$ will be bigger than the torque of $W$ the luggage will rotate counterclockwise and it'll lift up.

If you choose the rear wheel as pole to calculate the torque, the front wheel will lift off the ground when the torque of $T$ will be greater than the torque of $W$:

\begin{equation}
r_WW\sin\alpha\le r_TT\sin\beta
\end{equation}

where $r_w,r_T$ are the rispective distances between the pole (rear wheel) and the points of application of $W$ and $T$; $\alpha$ is the angle between the vectors $r_W$ and $W$, $\beta$ is the angle between the vectors $r_T$ and $T$.

Comment: Thank you. How do you know that it will lift up when the torque of $T$ will be bigger than the torque of $W$?

Comment: I've add something, maybe it is clearer

Answer (score 1):

Compute torque about the axle of the rear wheel.  This wheel being free to rotate, there is no  torque there.  When the front wheel leaves the ground, all you have are gravity (which we can consider as acting at the centre of mass), and the pulling force $T$.

Comment: My question is probably stupid, but why is there a connection between the wheel being free to rotate and that the torque there is null? I really can't visualize the torque, so I don't understand.

Comment: so should I find the torque about the rear wheel and put it equal to zero?

Comment: If you froze the rear axle so it couldn't rotate, friction between the ground and the rear wheel would produce a torque about that axle.

Comment: Yes, in static equilibrium the net torque about any point is $0$.